# Core Data - Generic Multithreading Violation

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm running this code on app launch and it crashes with:

> #0    0x00000001e4133088 in +[NSManagedObjectContext **Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor**] ()

There are other SO questions alluding to this but not in the sense of what I'm working with. I have a method that returns entities generically. The generic part works fine, the threading of my setup is somehow off. Here is the bare bones of my Core Data setup:

```
class Manager {
    
    static let shared: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /// sets up and returns the container
    }

    static func fetch<T: NSManagedObject>() throws -> [T] {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: String(describing: T.self))
        do {
            return try shared.viewContext.fetch(request) as [T] // <---- Crash line
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
}

// ...

func fetchFoos() {
    do {
        let foos: [Foo] = try Manager.fetch()
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that this only happens when I run the app on a device from Xcode. If I disconnect and just open the app without Xcode, it launched fine.

What stands out here that needs rearchitecting? I can't use iOS 15's `perform` or `performAndWait` due to supporting earlier OSs.

Answer (score 1):

This code would be OK *if you only ever use it on the main thread*. Since you're getting this specific crash when using `viewContext`, you seem to be calling this code from some thread other thread. That's not allowed with Core Data; managed object contexts are not thread safe, nor are managed objects.

A quick-but-probably-inadequate fix would be to surround the `fetch` call with either `perform` or `performAndWait` (both part of `NSManagedObjectContext`). That would make it safe to use `viewContext` on a different thread. But the objects you fetch would still be tied to the main thread, so you couldn't use them on the current thread without using `perform` or `performAndWait` again.

A more thorough fix would be to call `newBackgroundContext()` to create a new context for the current thread, and use that to fetch objects. But the fetched objects could only be used on that thread. You could also use `performBackgroundTask` to run a closure with a temporary context-- as long as you only use the fetched objects in that closure. (These methods are part of `NSPersistentContainer`). Both of these fixes will probably require other changes to your code, and you'll have to consider where and when you use the fetch results to figure out what those changes are.